# How can i return a navmenu button to previous style after clicking another button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal navigation menu with 5 buttons and i need to change the state of the clicked button.
This is the code i am using to achieve this :

**HTML :**

```
<div id="tab_menu">

<ul>
<li class="li_class"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li class="li_class"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li class="li_class"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li class="li_class"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
<li class="li_class"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#tab_menu {
        position:relative;
        width:800px;
        margin:0px auto;
        padding:20px;
        background-color:#fff;
    }

    ul {
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        margin:0px;
        background-color:#fff;
        list-style:none;
        overflow:auto;
    }

    ul li {
        float:left;
        width:150px;
        background-color:#1227B0;
        border:1px dashed #fff;
        border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
        height:30px;
    }

    ul li a {
        color:#fff;
        width:150px;
        text-align:center;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:block;
        font-size:14px;
        line-height:30px;
    }
```

**JQUERY :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.li_class').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#7787F1');
    });
});​
```

The problem is , The style of the button is changed to the color specified when clicked but i need to restore the original style to the button when i click another one , How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set all of the buttons back to the default color (assuming `#1227B0`, from your code), and then change `$(this)` afterwards.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.li_class').click(function() {
        $('.li_class').css('background-color', '#1227B0');
        $(this).css('background-color', '#7787F1');
    });
});
```

Comment: You can make it dynamic like with [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10190552/601179)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `class` names instead of direct CSS styling through jQuery. So when you need to mark a button as clicked, you add a class name with `.addClass('clicked');`, and remove it when you don't want it to be styled: `.removeClass('clicked');`.

Of course you need to create your CSS declaration:

```
.clicked {
  background-color: #7787F1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-` attributes for that:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li data-default-color="#1227B0" class="li_class"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li data-default-color="#1227B0" class="li_class"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li data-default-color="#1227B0" class="li_class"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li data-default-color="#1227B0" class="li_class"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
<li data-default-color="#1227B0" class="li_class"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.li_class').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#7787F1').siblings().each(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", $(this).data('default-color'));
    });
});​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wpzQj/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Reset the colors on every click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $('.li_class').click(function(){
               $('.li_class').css('background-color', '#1227B0');
               $(this).css('background-color', '#7787F1');
               return false;
           });
        });​
```

Here is a jsFiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/wpzQj/5/

Answer (score 0):

hi try following code

```
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.li_class').click(function(){
           $('.li_class').css('background-color', '#1227B0');
               $(this).css('background-color', '#7787F1');
           });
        });

    </script>
```

try demo here http://jsfiddle.net/wpzQj/8/

Comment: It's being done wrong. you should have done it with `$(this).siblings()` you code runs multiple times for each element * siblings. read my answer.